# How to get an especific part of a link with regex on python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, url

I'm inputting a lot of links from linked-in profiles into a program that will get me the id of those linked-in profiles. (Links are the strings, clicking on most of them will take you nowhere)

Example 1: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/facundo-b-barber%C3%A1-86bb41187/"

Example 2: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/facundo-b-barber%C3%A1-86bb41187/sometext"

If I input either of those examples the result will be: "facundo-b-barber%C3%A1-86bb41187"
The problem I run into is when I have something like this:

Example 3: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/facundo-b-barber%C3%A1-86bb41187/sometext/anothertext/"

Where the output is: "facundo-b-barber%C3%A1-86bb41187/sometext"

I've tried using re module in this function:

```py
def get_in(url):
    parsed = parse.urlparse(url)
    lin = parsed.path
    lin = re.search(r'/in/(.*)/', lin).group(1)
    print(lin)
    return lin
```

I want to get the id only and remove everything else in front and behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work ->

```
url.split('/')[4]
```

Examples:

```
>>> url =  "https://www.linkedin.com/in/facundo-b-barber%C3%A1-86bb41187/sometext/anothertext/"
>>> url.split('/')[4]
'facundo-b-barber%C3%A1-86bb41187'

>>> url = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/facundo-b-barber%C3%A1-86bb41187/sometext"
>>> url.split('/')[4]
'facundo-b-barber%C3%A1-86bb41187'

>>> url = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/facundo-b-barber%C3%A1-86bb41187/"
>>> url.split('/')[4]
'facundo-b-barber%C3%A1-86bb41187'
```

Comment: The url stays the same, in fact, pycharm is telling me .split is not having any effect on the variable

Comment: Function: 
`def get_in(url):
    url.split('/')[4]
    print(url)
    return url`

Console:
`https://www.linkedin.com/in/facundo-b-barber%C3%A1-86bb41187/test/web

Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: @BigXKu You should `print(url.split('/')[4])`

Comment: You're right, fixed it, but you should change the comment to `print(url.split('/')[4])`
for no future confusion with coming users

Comment: @BigXKu I don't see how any confusion should occur. The answer uses the console line input.